# Save\Load image info (path, resourceId) to device

Tags: android

I need to keep information about the image, which was the last time the user was working.

Before now I have saved full image in device memory. But it takes a very long time.

Now I have decided retain the information about the image. But in my application I use the images from the resources and images from the gallery.

How to store image information and how to get the image using the information during the next session with the application?

My failed attempt:

```
public abstract class BitmapDescriptor {

    protected static final String KEY_EXISTING_FLAG = "SavedBitmapDescriptor";
    protected static final String KEY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = "DescriptorType";
    protected static final String TYPE_IS_RESOURCE = "ResourceBitmapDescriptor";
    protected static final String TYPE_IS_GALLERY = "ResourceBitmapDescriptor";
    protected static final String KEY_RESOURCE_VALUE = "ValueOfResourceType";
    protected static final String KEY_GALLERY_VALUE = "ValueOfGalleryType";
    private static SharedPreferences pref;

    public static BitmapDescriptor load(SharedPreferences pref) {
        BitmapDescriptor.pref = pref;
        if (notSavedDescriptor()) {
            return null;
        }
        String descriptorType = getDesriptorType();
        if (descriptorType.equals(TYPE_IS_RESOURCE)) {
            return resourceDescriptor();
        } else if (descriptorType.equals(TYPE_IS_GALLERY)) {
            return galleryDescriptor();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("BitmapDescriptor.load(): Cannot load descriptor.");
        }
    }

    private static boolean notSavedDescriptor() {
        return !pref.getBoolean(KEY_EXISTING_FLAG, false);
    }

    private static String getDesriptorType() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, "");
    }

    private static BitmapDescriptor resourceDescriptor() {
        int resId = pref.getInt(KEY_RESOURCE_VALUE, -1);
        return new ResourceBitmapDescriptor(resId);
    }

    private static BitmapDescriptor galleryDescriptor() {
        String path = pref.getString(KEY_GALLERY_VALUE, "");
        return new GalleryBitmapDescriptor(path);
    }


    public abstract Bitmap getBitmap();

    public void save(SharedPreferences pref) {
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_EXISTING_FLAG, true);
        save(editor);
        editor.commit();
    }

    protected abstract void save(Editor editor);
}



public class ResourceBitmapDescriptor extends BitmapDescriptor {

    private final int resId;

    public ResourceBitmapDescriptor(int resId) {
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        Resources resources = GlobalContext.get().getResources();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void save(Editor editor) {
        editor.putString(KEY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, TYPE_IS_RESOURCE);
        editor.putInt(KEY_GALLERY_VALUE, resId);
    }
}


public class GalleryBitmapDescriptor extends BitmapDescriptor {

    private final String path;

    public GalleryBitmapDescriptor(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        File imgFile = new File(path);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @Override
    protected void save(Editor editor) {
        editor.putString(KEY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, TYPE_IS_GALLERY);
        editor.putString(KEY_GALLERY_VALUE, path);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the `save` method of your `ResourceBitmapDescriptor` class:

```
    editor.putString(KEY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, TYPE_IS_RESOURCE);
    editor.putInt(KEY_GALLERY_VALUE, resId);
```

You're using the wrong key for the resource id. It should assumedly be `KEY_RESOURCE_VALUE`:

```
    editor.putString(KEY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, TYPE_IS_RESOURCE);
    editor.putInt(KEY_RESOURCE_VALUE, resId);
```